# Multiple web project are hosted on IIS Express in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have solution with 3 project. Out 3 project 2 of the projects are of type web API and other one is ASP.Net MVC 5 web project. My solution is having the setting of "Single Start up project" which is pointing to Asp.net MVC 5 project.

Problem here is when I run the ASP.Net web project, It is getting hosted on IIS Express on some port. But other two Web API projects also getting hosted, even though I have not set the "multiple start up projects".

Is there any issue in vs 2013, or do i need to do some settings not to host all the web projects.

Note : I am using Visual Studio 2013 community edition.

Comment: Right click on the project, edit the properties, and there should be 'startup' options inside there that have options like "launch in web browser" or "do nothing".

Comment: Two web api project are already having the option "Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an external application" selected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just figured out by some more web search...

We have to set the project property "Always Start When Debugging" to false for which ever project we don't want to host.

See the link 
http://blog.geocortex.com/2010/06/04/always-start-when-debugging-preventing-multiple-visual-studio-development-servers-from-starting/